# Why has my Apple Push Notifications stopped working for development, but not for production?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate

I have four Enterprise iPhone apps that all utilize the Apple Push Notification System (APNS), and each application communicates via TCP with servers on our network. The servers contain software that automatically generate and send push notifications to users on certain events.

Until today, everything has been working fine, but suddenly any notification for my development iPhone throws an SSPI error. No problem with production units.

It happens for all four apps. Any notification that is sent through gateway.push.apple.com:2195 works fine, but sending through gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 returns the error.

The Apple developer website indicates that the APNS sandbox server is available, so I have to assume the problem is not a server crash. I have received no email notifications that any certificates have expired, but they shouldn't anyway, because they are all current.

My question is, is there something else I need to be looking at to see where this problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Bill, we had the same exact issue starting March 9, 2019, when our VoIP APNS certificate stopped testing against Sandbox APN server, but would still work against Production. Since there is only one type of VoIP certificate which should work on both Sandbox and Production, we assume there was a hiccup on Apple's side.

We contacted Apple's Tech team, but they referred us to their generic documentation on Tech Note TN2265 (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

Today (March 14) VoIP certificate magically started authenticating against both Prod and Sandbox like it normally did before March 9.

Please try again and see if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Yes, the sandbox is working for me now too. I had filed an Apple bug report AND contacted Developer Support, and remarkably was getting some appropriate responses from both entities. At any rate, they seem to have fixed the problem. I am relieved to know that it wasn't something I had screwed up with certificates, because that stuff is extremely complicated for my simple mind.

Comment: The issue seems to have re-emerged as of July 25, 2019.

Comment: Yes, for me too. I have sent in a trouble report. I hope you will too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same or separate certificates for your development vs production APNS? If you're using different certs, check to make sure your development certificate doesn't hasn't expired.

If you're using the same certificate, ensure that your server configuration matches the correct certificate and app id information. If either is wrong it will fail.

These are the usual issues I've run into with this kind of problem.

Comment: @Malcom thanks for your response. I am using separate certificates for development and production. Since I am also developing the iOS app, my iPhone is in development "mode," preventing it from receiving notifications through the production certificate. And both certificates are recently renewed. I just wonder if I am overlooking some kind of developer's certificate that may have expired without me knowing, though I see nothing in my list of certificates that would indicate that.

Comment: I should add that I have four separate iPhone apps that use push notifications, and they all failed for the developer certificate at the same time.

Comment: i am getting this issue since yesterday. Production still working fine but sandbox not receiving, tried deleting app and regenerating certificates etc nothing fixed. Anyone getting APNS issue in sanbox mode?